# Kentico 9: How to grant permission to built-in types (classes)?

Tags: kentico

So I have created a custom module that allows certain users to create cities and associate them to **States** (cms.state).

For the UI element, I used an `Object Listing` template where the `Object Type` is set to **State (cms.state)**:

[image]
[image]

This presents a list of US states as expected:

[image]

This only works as expected when logged in as `Global Administrator`. I need to be able to grant view permission to this page for a *specific role*, who certainly should not have Global Administration permissions. When a user who is only assigned to an **EDITOR** role views this page, they are told they do not have permission:

[image]

I have searched high and low through roles, permissions, users etc.....and I cannot find a way to grant view permissions to **class** `cms.state`. I have tried scripting a permission into the SQL database and creating a role permission for it, I have tried altering the `cms.state` record in the `CMS_Class` table (flagging `ClassIsDocumentType`, `ClassShowAsSystemTable`) and I cannot get it to show in any of the permission assignments.

Any guidance on this topic would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

> EDIT: Capture of Globalization Module Permission Tab showing inability
>   to customize permissions

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have your [permissions defined](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Creating+custom+modules#Creatingcustommodules-Definingmodulepermissions).

Also, I believe cms.state is a global Kentico reserved class name so you'd have to rename your class to have a different name.  Unless you're reusing the existing class/object.  If you are, you may need to modify the permissions within the Globalization module to be able to edit the state object(s).

** UPDATE **
Ok I see what you're doing now.  I believe the Globalization module does not have Read/Modify permissions and you can't add them either.  IMHO it's best to create your own country/state classes because Kentico has some weird setup with how they work and are linked.  This will give you the flexiblity you need/want in order to allow your users what they need.

Comment: Brenden - I am listing the built-in cms.state class in kentico, and I have not been able to figure out how to change Globalization module permissions. It doesn't show in Roles or Permissions Module, and the Globalization Module Permissions are not editable (Please see screen capture in the question EDIT above)

Comment: Also, I'm not trying to grant permissions to EDIT the states, I only want a non-admin to be allowed to VIEW them. It's an Object Listing template....